# Grouping by part of a postcode

Tags: mysql

I am developing a php/mysql system for a legal advice agency. Clients are recorded in a table ‘clients’ which contains (amongst others) the columns clientid and postcode. (Note this is in the UK)

A client then registers for advice and a matter is opened. The matters table contains columns mattered, client and legalid.

Legalid refers to a table ‘legal’ which has columns legalid and legal (legal is the type of legal advice e.g. employment, housing etc)

What I need to be able to do is to count the number of people receiving advice in particular areas grouped by the first part of the UK postcode. I think I can do this except I don’t know how to do the postcode grouping as the first part could be 2, 3 or 4 characters. For example, the postcodes might be E2 6TY or E14 7YU - I want to group by E2 and E14 etc. Also, in some cases a client doesn't want to provide the whole postcode so only the 1st part is entered.

Has anybody any guidance as to how I might be able to do this grouping?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(postal_code, ' ', 1)
```

There are lots of posts on stackoverflow where people use and give examples of substring_index so just do a search for it.